# Different Home page for Mobile without changing URL

Tags: mobile

Hi I am looking for a solution .

I want to redirect my mobile user to different Home Page . ie

https://example.com/mobile

I have created a function in Function.php

```
function so16165211_mobile_home_redirect(){
if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
    $redirect_url = 'https://example.com/mobile/';
    header('Location: ' . $redirect_url );
}}add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16165211_mobile_home_redirect' );
```

Now its working perfectly the thing is I don't want Mobile to show 
https://example.com/mobile rather
https://example.com

Any solution for it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't, this will only invite more problems. Google will probably dislike it, but even more important: an URL should always (in my opinion) display one site, not something completely different for X

Comment: The solution is to create a responsive layout that works on all screen sizes. "Mobile" doesn't mean small screen anymore.

Comment: The Layout of mobile is complete different, Its App like Style.That's why responsive its not an option .

Comment: And why the different URL? I mostly use Wikipedia's mobile pages on desktop as well, because they are neat and clean

Comment: The Frontpage of my website is Stafic Page for Dekstop.
That's why I created Different page for mobile.

Comment: any help guys? ...

Comment: I am still looking for a solution but I have a lead. The martfury theme uses some technique and works really as expected. No url change, but they have a field to add the mobile home page. And we can design the app like design in that page, the url remains same for desktop and mobile. But I dont know how they did this. hope I will get some ideas. yes template change works but I want it to work with elementor...

Comment: hey bruuudas use this "Specific Content For Mobile – Customize the mobile version without redirections" or look into its code and recreate it...